# Number of terms in a DNF equals the number of truth outputs

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, boolean-ring

In a Boolean function $f$, it seems that the number of terms in a Disjunctive Normal Form (DNF) is equal to the number of truth outputs of $f$. For example,

If $f=A+B$, then clearly, $f$ has $2^2-1=3$ truth outputs.

Also, DNF of $f$ is $f=AB+A\bar{B}+\bar{A}B$ (three terms). Likewise, we can show that DNF of $f=A+B+C$ contains $7$ terms, but its number of truth outputs is also $7$.

> Is it true in general that the number of terms in a DNF is equal to the number of truth outputs of $f$?

Comment: What do you mean by $A+B$? $A\vee B$?

Comment: @MaximNikitin yes, it is.....

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about DNF in general that's not true. For instance, $(A\vee\neg A)\vee B_1\vee\dots\vee B_n$ is identically true but one of it's DNF is $A\vee\neg A$. Also you can duplicate conjunctions: $$A\vee A\vee\dots\vee A\vee\neg A\vee\neg A\dots\vee\neg A$$

and disjuntions:

$$(A\vee\neg A)\vee(A\vee\neg A)\vee\dots\vee(A\vee\neg A).$$

But if we are talking about *perfect* DNF then yes, you are right. In perfect DNF each conjunction includes all the variables of the formula and there are no duplicates. The reason is the following: we build a perfect DNF looking at a truth table and matching a unique conjunction to each of the truth outputs.

Comment: By {\it perfect} DNF, do you mean Complete Disjunctive Normal Form?. By the ways, I haven't heard of {\it perfect} DNF.

Comment: Probably that's what I mean. Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker and don't know the exact name of this object. :-)

Comment: By the way, in my answer I gave a definition of what I mean.

Comment: Yes, your definition seems to be of DNF. So, the answer to the question would be true in general. Moreover, the answer will not be true in case of a complete DNF, because a complete DNF of a function in $n$ variables will contain $2^n$ terms.